# How to reform a json having 1 core object with a specific property

Tags: javascript, json, angular6

I am having 1core of object in json and these object have supplier property. There are other objects having same supplier name but different other values. So I want to reform this json in the below format.

## Initially I am having below json.

```
[
{val: 2, supplier:"A"},
{val: 2, supplier:"b"},
{val: 1, supplier:"c"},
{val: 0, supplier:"b"},
{val: 3, supplier:"A"},
{val: 5, supplier:"c"}
]
```

## I want in below format.

```
{
"A": [{val: 2, supplier:"A"},{val: 3, supplier:"A"}],
"b": [{val: 2, supplier:"b"},{val: 0, supplier:"b"}],
"c":[{val: 1, supplier:"c"}, {val: 5, supplier:"c"}]
.....
}
```

The most Important factor over here is number of data. I know this much data take a considerable time. Which way is best server side or client side? If client side then I want a very optimize way to implement. I already know normal way with forEach and other looping like filter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all items. Skip errors where supplier doesn't exist.

```
    //where p is the object that needs sorting
    var p = [ {val: 2, supplier:"A"}, {val: 2,           supplier:"b"}, {val: 1, supplier:"c"}, {val: 0, supplier:"b"}, {val: 3, supplier:"A"}, {val: 5, supplier:"c"} ];

   var g = {};
   for( var x = 0; x < p.length; x++){
      if(!p || !p[x] || p[x].supplier === void(0)){ continue; }
      if( g[p[x].supplier]){
          g[p[x].supplier].push( p[x] );
          continue;
       }
      g[p[x].supplier] = [p[x]];
    }
```

Comment: Good solution !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on server side which is a good way because the service should be doing data process and angular app should be concerned with view and user interaction.
Now to format the data you may take following steps.

1. Get all the supplier values in an array like ["A", "b", "c", "A"].
2. Remove the duplicates from this array such that no value repeats in this array.
3. Now create a json object an use these values as keys and push the objects as values that contain respective supplier number. Each key will have an array as a value that will contain those respective objects with respective supplier.

Comment: However I have to for loop to this and complexcity will goes to number of records. That I donot want. Is there any chaining methods like filter().map()... perform in single way.